# Dijit widget constructor throws "calling chained constructor" error

Tags: javascript, inheritance, widget, dojo

I've a `Base` class that inherits from `[_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin]`. `Base` is properly working. Now I inherit this `Base` in another class which is not working

```
define([
   "dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/parser", ...
], function(declare, parser, ...){
    return declare("mc.widgets.Base", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
        templateString: 
            '<div class="mc-note-base">'+
            '</div>',
        constructor: function(argv){
            var self = this.inherited(arguments);
            return self;
        },
        data: function(){

        },
        postCreate: function(){
            ...
        }
    })
});
```

Derived class

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare", "mc/base/path", "mc/widgets/Base"
], function(declare, path, Base){
    return declare("mc.widgets.Derived", [Base], {});
})
```

The Derived Class throws

> Error: declare mc.widgets.Derived: calling chained constructor with inherited

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because the `constructor` portion of a Widget's lifecycle is handled with a special chaining mechanism, designed for more flexible Widget creation. You can [read here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/_base/declare.html#manual-constructor-chaining) for more information, but the part that applies to your situation says:

> Superclass constructors are always called automatically, and always before the subclass constructor. This convention reduces boilerplate in 90% of cases. If it doesn’t fit your needs see Manual Constructor Chaining below. For all other methods, use this.inherited(arguments) to call the superclass method of the same name.

If you simply remove the `this.inherited(arguments)` call from your Widget's constructor method, your problem will be resolved. [Here is a simple jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H7Zh8/35/) that mimics your Widget set up and demonstrates the solution.